# How do I load my array into multiple text boxes?

Tags: c#

I'm a student currently working on a powerball program for class. I have made an array with random numbers and need to load each number into an it's own text field. This seems like it would be rather simple to do but I'm just stuck. Would love some help on this!

ok sorry! kinda new to this place and I don't have a whole lot done.

```
   private void btnQuickPlayNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randCheck = 0;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] powerball5 = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < powerball5.Length; )
        {
            randCheck = rand.Next(0, 60);

            while (!(powerball5.Contains(randCheck)))
            {
                powerball5[i] = randCheck;
                i++;
            }


        }
    }
```

this is all that I have done so far. I was thinking there might be a way to increment through the text boxes using the for loop but I'm not sure on this. My teacher told me not to use a bunch of if statement to do this.

Comment: how about showing some code that you currently had.. it's very simple but what you are actually asking for is for someone to do it for you so that you don't have to think it out yourself..

Comment: Show us what you already done, describe where exactly you stuck, and tag question with winforms, wpf, or asp.net (mvc) tag

Comment: OP - There are plenty of ways to deal with your issue across various platforms. Please be more specific.

Comment: I get where your coming from so my bad for being new and not really knowing what part of my code would be helpful to show you. I don't have a whole lot done on this program yet and this about the only thing I don't feel like I know what to do. I'm not asking someone to write my code for me. I'm simply asking if I can have some help with how to push numbers from an array into multiple text boxes.

Comment: SeventhLogic just show what code you have show parts for example the code of how you are generating Random numbers and the Textboxes that you have setup.. for future reference.. always show relative code that reflects your current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have *four* numbers in that array. If you have a definitive number of indices, 4 of them, you have to have four TextBox objects.

```
    List<String> = new List<String>();
    foreach (int myInt in myArray)
    {
        List.add(myInt.ToString());
    }
```

Then in the main class, or runtime:

```
TextBox1.Text = List.get(0);
TextBox2.Text = List.get(1);
TextBox3.Text = List.get(2);
TextBox4.Text = List.get(3);
```

Modify for more numbers if needed ;)

EDIT:

```
    int randCheck = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] powerball5 = new int[5];



    for (int i = 0; i < powerball5.Length; )
    {
        randCheck = rand.Next(0, 60);

        while (!(powerball5.Contains(randCheck)))
        {
            powerball5[i] = randCheck;
            var textBox = this.Controls.Find("textBOX" + i, true) as TextBox;
            textBox.Text = powerball5[i].ToString();
            i++;
        }


    }
```

Make sure you have textBOX(1-5)!

Comment: Are you sure question is not about asp.net mvc? Are you sure there less than 50 numbers? And there is no `add` and `get` methods on List which is not even created in your code

Comment: @Iazyberezovsky Pardon? I gave an answer and if it's different I'll modify it to suit the change in language. Read the answer, "modify for more numbers as needed"

Comment: Same here but looking at your code.. here is some helpful advice.. are you familiar with `foreach(Control c in parent.Controls){}` then check within the foreach loop the Type if it's TextBox then you can truly use the Array to populate the textboxes without having to hard code all of them.. think of it this way.. if you have 100 TextBox Controls and you want to clear all 100 hundred of them..would you write 100 times TextBox ControlName.Clear() for all of them or write a simple foreach loop to clear them all.. use that same principal to fill them randomly..

Comment: It'd still work if you had 100, as it's in the loop. I'm assuming the powerBall[] length (It's 5) is equivalent to the amount of textBOX's

Comment: @DJKRAZE Also, I'm FLATTERED with your comments. :P

Comment: yes it would but how many people name their controls as Textbox1 , TextBox2, etc..lol it would work but I would have gone with a foreach loop checking only the controls for textbox but good answer Whippet.. `Whippet Good...! per DEVO LOL`

Comment: Thanks for the answers I'm sorry I came across as lazy. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but does this help?

```
txtNum1.Text = numArray[0].ToString();
```

With that you can repeat it for each index of your array.

```
txtNum2.Text = . . .
txtNum3.Text = . . .
```

and so on.

Comment: nowhere even close with this answer ..Anthony

Comment: I meant it as an example, sorry.  I'll make it more clear.

Comment: Anthony look at how Whippet did his answer.. it's better to do things in a loop rather than having to do them by hard coding ..Whippet could actually do his code by doing a ForEach on Controls and checking to see if the Type of Control is TextBox, then based on the control that is found in the foreach loop can populate the necessary TextBoxes randomly and not have to write out each textbox.