# C# - loading text boxes with a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I'm back looking for a solution on how to load my array into certain text boxes. I posted a similar question the other day. The answer that was provided was good however now I'm having what I believe to be a problem with positioning within the code. This is what I have:

```
    private void btnQuickPlayNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randCheck = 0;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] powerball5 = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < powerball5.Length; )
        {
            randCheck = rand.Next(0, 60);

            while (!(powerball5.Contains(randCheck)))
            {
                powerball5[i] = randCheck;

                foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (x is TextBox)
                    {
                        ((TextBox)x).Text = powerball5[i].ToString();                            
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }                
        }
    }
```

Now this loads all the text boxes on my forum and that is fine however it is loading the same number in all of them. This is a powerball program and I need to load my array into the boxes as so:

textbox1 = powerball5[0];
textbox2 = powerball5[1];
ect., ect.

I have a total of 5 boxes that I'm trying to load. We came to the conclusion that the reason this loads the same number into all of them is that the position of the foreach loop doesn't allow for the array to be loaded and the counter to increment. I have tried moving it around and even making its own method, but when I do it as it's own method I get an index out of range error. So I'm a little lost on what to do. Any help would be greatly appriciated. If you need any more info I will try to update this the best I can to meet the needs of everyone. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Is this WinForms, ASP.NET, or WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: WinForms, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't get this UI.  You are using a textbox to allow the user to *edit* a lottery number?  Use labels or a listbox or a listview.  If you need an array of labels then just create one in your code instead of trying to find the label back later.  Btw, a powerball lottery doesn't permit the same number twice, you need a shuffle.

Comment: SeventhLogic why are you posting the same code that you posted yesterday..? the link was closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843192/how-do-i-load-my-array-into-multiple-text-boxes `Didn't the answer there work for you` I think that you really need to look at the code that you have and start Debugging the existing code along with the code that was provided to you yesterday..
`i++;` needs to be inside the foreach loop` I would suggest looking at how to increment variables in a foreach loop as well as a While loop..

Comment: I would agree with this and I tried it. All I got from that was an index out of range error. I thought the answer was going to work and after sitting down with my class and professor we came up with a solution but I have not had the chance to implement that yet. The last question was closed so I re posted.

Answer (score 0):

This code loads the same number into every text box 5 times so you only get the last number in all.

```
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)x).Text = powerball5[i].ToString();                            
                }
            }
```

You should probably structure it more like this:

```
int[] whiteNumbers = DrawPowerballWhites();

// should be in its own function -- DisplayPowerballNumbers(int[] whites, int powerball)
var whiteTextboxes = this.Controls
                         .OfType<TextBox>()
                         .Where(t => IsWhiteTextbox(t))
                         .Select((textbox,index) => new {textbox, index});

foreach(var indexedTextBox in whiteTextboxes)
{
   indexedTextbox.textbox.Text = whiteNumbers[indexedTextbox.index];
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for the post. I appreciate all the comments and effort put forth here. I won't be able to look at this much until later tonight but thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

To match your code you could use this:

```
    int randCheck = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] powerball5 = new int[5];
    TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[5];
    int count = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < powerball5.Length; i++)
    {
        randCheck = rand.Next(0, 60);

        do
        {
            randCheck = rand.Next(0, 60);
        } while (Array.IndexOf(powerball5, randCheck) != -1);
        powerball5[i] = randCheck;
    }

    foreach (TextBox x in this.Controls)
    {
            x.Text = powerball5[count].ToString();
            count++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. Sadly I'm working till much later tonight so I will not have the chance to test this out until then.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this before, the random class uses numbers that appear random that are generated on the host machine, however it refreshes about every 20 - 30 ms so your 'for' loop is moving so fast it the randoms wont refresh, try adding a '`system.threading.thread.sleep(25);`' into your for loop.